# PhoneGap Build application doesn't fire battery-related events

Tags: cordova, dom-events, phonegap-build, battery, batterylevel

I have a [`phonegap-bootstrap` project at GitHub](https://github.com/trejder/phonegap-bootstrap) -- a demo application, written in PhoneGap 2.9. I've placed event handlers for every event supported by PhoneGap. All of them fires without any problems, except for battery-related events.

I was more then sure, that this is because of missing permission, but it turned out to be wrong asumption.

So... Can someone tell me, what is wrong with the following code:

```
var app = 
{
    init: function()
    {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.deviceReadyHandler, false);

        app.writeEventLog('app.init();');
    },

    deviceReadyHandler: function()
    {
        document.addEventListener('batterylow', app.batteryLowHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('batterystatus', app.batteryStatusHandler, false);
        document.addEventListener('batterycritical', app.batteryCriticalHandler, false);
    },

    batteryLowHandler: function(info){app.batteryHandler('low', info);},
    batteryStatusHandler: function(info){app.batteryHandler('status', info);},
    batteryCriticalHandler: function(info){app.batteryHandler('critical', info);},

    batteryHandler: function(type, info)
    {
        $('#lblBatteryLevel').html(info.level + '%');
        $('#lblBatteryPlugged').html((info.isPlugged) ? 'yes' : 'no');

        app.writeEventLog('app.battery' + event + 'Handler(level = ' + info.level +', isPlugged = ' + info.isPlugged + ');');
    }
}

app.init();
```

For some reason, beyond my imagination, PhoneGap Build application isn't firing battery-related events. And only those battery-related.

Battery-related events never gets fired and code inside "global" (general) battery handler (`batteryHandler`) isn't ever executed, so `lblBatteryLevel` and `lblBatteryPlugged` divs remains in their initial values ("*[waiting]*").

And all other event handlers are coded exactly in the same way. Declared in `deviceReadyHandler`:

```
document.addEventListener('pause', app.pauseHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('resume', app.resumeHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('online', app.onlineHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('offline', app.offlineHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('menubutton', app.menuButtonHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('searchbutton', app.searchButtonHandler, false);
```

And then defined as log-writing events only:

```
/**
 * Demo purpose only events.
 */
pauseHandler: function(){app.writeEventLog('app.pauseHandler();');},
resumeHandler: function(){app.writeEventLog('app.resumeHandler();');},
onlineHandler: function(){app.writeEventLog('app.onlineHandler();');},
offlineHandler: function(){app.writeEventLog('app.offlineHandler();');},
menuButtonHandler: function(){app.writeEventLog('app.menuButtonHandler();');},
searchButtonHandler: function(){app.writeEventLog('app.searchButtonHandler();');},
```

All of them fires, except for battery-related ones.

I was more then sure, that this is because of missing permission, but I triple checked, that line `<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>` is placed in my `config.xml` file.

I tried [asking](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/does_phonegap_build_apps_supports_all_phonegap_events) guys at [PhoneGap Build Get Satisfaction](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi) forum, but got no advice, what can be wrong.

I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trejder/XWCTC/), where `HTML` part contains my entire `config.xml` file and `Javascript` part contains most parts out of my Javascript code, those related to battery. Maybe someone have some time, reviewing it. I can't find any mistakes there and the battery-related code is still not working.

Comment: have you solved that, trejder?

Comment: @zok: You're referring to the question, I've asked a year ago, that I don't recall anymore. However, my [`phonegap` repo at Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/trejder/phonegap) does contain `battery` demo application (among others), which as far as I remember **is working fine**. So, we may assume, that I've solved the general battery problem, though I don't know right now, what I did to solve it? :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [`phonegap-battery` repo at GitHub](https://github.com/trejder/phonegap-battery) contains `battery` demo application, which **seems to be working**.

It looks, that I've solved the battery problem, though I don't recall right now, what I did to solve it.

I only recall, that with some help from PhoneGap Build community / PGB GetSatisfaction forum, I managed to find what was wrong and fixed battery demo application to be fully operable.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside deviceReadyHandler function. I think the battery events are called even before device is ready.

Comment: What you wrote seems to be against [PhoneGap API Documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#batterystatus), which specifically says: "_Applications typically should use window.addEventListener to attach an event listener once the deviceready event fires_".

Comment: document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

Comment: To cite my own question: "_And all other event handlers are coded exactly in the same way. Declared in `deviceReadyHandler`_". What are we talking about? You're telling me to do, what is already done?

Answer (score 0):

Add battery status plugin to your project.

Open command prompt

> cd your_project_dir
>
> phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.battery-status

Comment: What is the reason in adding plugin, if I'm asking about problems solving this using core API? I don't want to use any plugins here.

Comment: Cordova/Phonegap 3.x core api has got minimal set of device functions. Some features should add as plugin.
See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs

Comment: Great, but this question is about code written in **PhoneGap 2.9**. A lot (really a lot) of things has changed in PhoneGap 3.